# Failed on using Sencha Touch to package a very simple native app for android

Tags: android, extjs, touch

I am learning how to develop app with Sencha Touch. When I try to package a very simple app to run on android emulator, I failed. The screen just got stuck on dots keep blinking.

All I did is create a new project using Secha CMD, and then replace the content of app.js with the following:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Sencha',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                html: [
                    '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
                    '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
                    "<p>You're creating the Getting Started app. This demonstrates how ",
                    "to use tabs, lists, and forms to create a simple app</p>",
                    '<h2>Sencha Touch</h2>'
                ].join("")
            }
        ]
    });
  }
});
```

I am using Sencha Cmd v4.0.0.203, ruby 1.9.3p448, windows 8
My app works fine when I test it on my PC using IIS as a web server, no errors.

I found a similar thread here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238441-App-hangs-at-three-dots-blinking-screen
but the solution mentioned in this thread does't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow access to external domains in your `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```